IFS with multiple conditions check in Google Sheet
I am trying to get a result that meets the following conditions..

If the Craft is Crane Operator or all Riggers including Rigger I, Rigger II, Rigger III then display the value of column F in the column H
If the Craft is H.E. Operator then display the value of column G in the column H
All other Crafts excluding Crane Operators, H.E. Operators and all Rigger including Rigger I, Rigger II, Rigger III then display the value of column E in the column H

I tried the below formula but does not work..
=IFS(C7="Crane Operator", QUERY(F7,"SELECT *"),C7="Rigger III", QUERY(F7,"SELECT *"),C7="Rigger II", QUERY(F7,"SELECT *"),C7="Rigger I", QUERY(F7,"SELECT *"),C7="H.E. Operator", QUERY(G7,"SELECT *"))

You can access Goggle Sheet to check the data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_jOn0vyv6osaoppeU9TXX1boOlZbnoCFy3eWsddP7uc/edit?gid=14738129#gid=14738129

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

I need to check few more conditions:
If any H. E. Operator or Heavy Driver has a Valid or Expiring Soon Aramco License (Column F), Column H should display the value of Column F, otherwise G or E.
Thank you

Please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

Crafts are in column D rather than column C. Use regexmatch(), like this:
=ifs( 
  regexmatch(D7, "Crane Operator|Rigger I{1,3}"), F7, 
  D7 = "H.E. Operator", G7, 
  true, E7 
)

See regexmatch().

Try this;
=IF(OR(D7 = "Crane Operator",D7 = "Rigger I", D7 = "Rigger II", D7 ="Rigger III",D7),F7,IF(D7 = "H.E. Operator", G7, E7))

